# VM VirtualBox Network troubles - cannot clone git repos or install nmap

Tags: git, virtual-machine, virtualbox, yocto

I'm working on a VM with Ubuntu and Windows 10 host pc. I try to `bitbake linux-yoco-rt` and got the following **error message:**

```
fatal: unable to connect to git.yoctoproject.org:
git.yoctoproject.org[0: 140.211.169.56]: errno=Connection refused
```

---

So I tried to clone the repo separately with `git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-4.8.git` and got the same error.

---

- I can ping the website with `ping git.yoctoproject.org`
- Firewall is deactivated
- I do not use a proxy on the VM
- The VM is connected via "NAT"
- I tried to use https instead of git (same error occured)

  ---

Any ideas what could solve the issue or what kind of debugging I could try (commands, etc)?

---

**Edit**
I tried to install nmap to analyse the network. This thows some errors like:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nmap/nmap_7.01-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to ch.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:620:0:1002::20). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:620:0:1002::20 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the VM networking is broken.  This would be a virtualbox/windows problem and nothing to do with yocto.